# return data from jquery $.post

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, json

I want to have a simple function where i can insert a sqlQuery and get a database answer in json-format like this:

```
  function ExecuteQuery(query){
    $.post("sql.php", { "query": query },
     function(data){ return data;  },
     "json");
   }
```

The response i get is undefined, I think i have misunderstood something quite basic but i don't know what, can anybody give me a hint?

Comment: This gets asked frequently... Here are a few examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229307/jquery-getjson-return-value-to-the-caller-function
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470467/return-value-from-ajax-request-to-another-function
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712800/having-trouble-getting-a-return-value-from-a-javascript-callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you want something you cannot have :-)  Instead of thinking in terms of a function that *returns* a value, write yourself a function that takes *another function* as an argument and calls it when the data is available.

```
function ExecuteQuery(query, callback){
  $.post("sql.php", { "query": query },
   function(data){ callback(data);  },
   "json");
 }
```

Now, when you call that function, you'll pass it a function that can take the server response and do something with it.

```
ExecuteQuery("whatever", function(results) {
  // do something with "results"
});
```

Comment: That was my first solution but i thought i could make it like a return-function. But you kind of solved my problem, now i don't need to try it any more, thanks!

Comment: You don't need to say `function(data){ callback(data); }`, you can just say `callback`, can't you?

Comment: Yes if you've already got a named function sitting around, that's fine!

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something with the data - you can't just return it. The outer function returns instantly, but the inner function returns later, after the server round-trip. Try doing `alert(data)` to see how it works.

Comment: Yes it works well but the ting is i want to return the data, i have tried to save the data too but same problem